# use %post_title% in description (All in one SEO Pack)

Tags: plugin-all-in-one-seo

I am not able to use %post_title% in the description part ,it's displaying as %post_title% itself.. we can use other tags like %blog_title% , but the %post_title% is not working ..
please help..

thanks

Answer (score 3):

See these posts:

1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/instead-of-seeing-the-actual-post-title-for-pages-i-see-the-text-post_title
2. http://caspianit.co.uk/all-in-one-seo-post_title

Someone says there:

If you use All in one SEO, you need to set Page Title Format: %page_title%. Your page title will be displayed properly.

I have not tried it myself

Answer (score 0):

I have a written up a fix for this here:
[how to get post_title as text in your meta description](http://blog.3-prime.com/2012/02/aio-seo-pack-wordpress-post_title-as-text/)

Use the variable `%wp_title%`.

Comment: An answer should be more than [barely more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: Good point, so the fix I found with the help of the plugin author was to use this variable: 
%wp_title%
This loaded the post's title just fine!